# Splitting shared memory?

Tags: c++, winapi

A block of shared memory is allocated using `CreateFileMapping()` and the handle to it is given. Some data were written using `MapViewOfFile()` -- call it 'source'

Now I wish to split the shared memory into many small blocks and to get the handles to them.
Is there a way to do that while not calling `CreateFileMapping()` again and copying from 'source'?

`OpenFileMapping()` and `MapViewOfFile()` with appropriate offsets will work but the problem is, in that case the process that calls `OpenFileMapping()` get to have access to data written in 'source' by other processes and they might be corrupted by using a wrong offset.

Long story short, I'm looking for something like `OpenFileMapping(String name, UINT **offset**, ...)`

---

The last sentence was misleading.

What I'm really trying to do is something like this:

```
<Host process>
HANDLE hShm = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, ..., "shm");
void* pShm = MapViewOfFile(hShm);
UINT numShms = *(UINT*)pShm;   // first 4 bytes stores number of shared memory blocks
HANDLE *hShmSplit = new HANDLE[numShms];    
for(size_t i=0; i<numShms; i++) {
   TCHAR shmName[32];
   wsprintf(shmName, "shm%d", i);
   // suppose offset is set
   pShm+=offset;
   hShmSplit[i] = *CreateFileMappingFromExistingMapping*(pShm, shmName);
}
CloseHandle(hShm);   // no longer used

<Client process>
TCHAR* shmName="shm1";
HANDLE hShm = OpenFileMapping(shmName);
LPVOID p = MapViewOfFile(hShm);
// use shared memory 
// Now the client process has access to shm1 but not to shm2, shm3, or other shm_x's.
```

Comment: ... Why can't you just pass around pointers to the middle of it?

Comment: It's a multiprocess project so...

Comment: How do you expect the other processes to get at the open file then?

Comment: By name: OpenFileMapping(..., LPCTSTR name)

Comment: So then what you need is some way of passing around *valid offsets*.

Comment: Even if the host process always sends valid offsets, client processes can always use invalid ones, though. And there's nothing I can do about it.

Comment: But... they could do that *even if you give them the mapping*...

Comment: Microsoft has `__based` pointers for exactly this purpose. It automatically splits/combines a base address and offset, so you can easily (for example) transmit offsets from one process and use them in another with a minimum of work.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams No, the can't because the handles are different if the shared memory were re-CreateFileMapped(). If the shared memory blocks were identified by only the handles (and not by offsets) then the client processes can't manipulate other processes' shared memory blocks.

Comment: @JerryCoffin That means there's an API that returns file HANDLE from existing file pointer?

Comment: @JeffreyGoines don't you control the processes in question? Why would they manipulate other processes' shared memory blocks?

Comment: @jalf I hope to support 3rd-party client processes

Comment: You cannot create file mappings from other file mappings, but in this case you don't need to. Use the `dwFileOffsetHigh`, `dwFileOffsetLow`, and `dwNumberOfBytesToMap` parameters to `MapViewOfFile` to map a subset of the file mapping into each client process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shared memory works by mapping the same physical memory page into the virtual address space of several processes.  Once a process has access to a memory page, it has access to the whole page.  Memory pages are 4KB in length (Itanium notwithstanding).

Hence if you could split up a mapped file into pieces, the pieces would have to start on page boundaries and be exact multiples of 4KB in size.  So it wouldn't be that useful.

If you want to securely share different bits of memory with different client processes, you'll have to use a separate mapping for each one.